# What is the origin of "Release early and often"?

Tags: release-management, agile

Where does the origin of the [Release Early, Release Often (RERO)](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22Release%20early%20and%20often.%22) principle come from?

Comment: This seems like a valid question. I don't understand why it's gotten so much negative attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the earliest references to this term originate in Jim McCarthy's book [Dynamics of Software Development](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1556158238). This term seems to also be embedded in the Lean Startup movement, which built upon ideas in [Lean Manufacturing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lean_manufacturing), [TRIZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIZ), and other sources explaining how to evaluate an experimental product and check if it fits the market before investing too much effort in its completion.

Answer (score 3):

Eric S. Raymond is credited with popularizing "Release Early, Release Often" in his essay ["The Cathedral and the Bazaar"](http://www.catb.org/~esr/writings/cathedral-bazaar/cathedral-bazaar/ar01s04.html) where he credits Linus Torvalds as using that approach in the development of Linux to it's success.